# BeautifulSoup4 cannot select by id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the name of the Facebook fan page which under `id='seo_h1_tag'`,
but the result is `Could not find element`.

I tried to replace `seo_h1_tag` with `facebook` which is the first ID in the HTML and it works, giving the output as `Element exist`. What is the problem of the code?

```
#! python3
import requests,os,bs4
url='https://www.facebook.com/pg/BANDMAIDTW/photos/?tab=album&album_id=1520840718217296'

#Download the page
print('Downloading page %s...' + url)
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

element =soup.select('#seo_h1_tag')
if element==[]:
    print('Could not find element.')
else:
    print('Element exist')
```

Comment: The contents of the Facebook page are generated dynamically with JavaScript. The page source doesn't contain the tags you're after. `requests` module can't do anything about JavaScript. You need to use [**`Selenium`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).

Comment: Thank you very much. I try to use Selenium to do it.